# Bootstrap Carousel animation overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have setup the bootstrap carousel the way I want it but the animation is overlapping and I can't seem to figure out why. When the slide happens, there's an overlapping of the current slide onto itself which gives a blurry effect.

Kindly help where I went wrong.

**[DEMO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aningbo/a5zLhjmr/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 PridelCr">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">

<a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/u7dfocir9/pridel_header_1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
<h3>Slide 1</h3>
<p>This is the first slide which is going to be awesome.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">

<a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/nuyaeifp1/pridel_header_2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
<h3>Slide 2</h3>
<p>This is the second slide which is not as awesome.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">

<a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/r32rrk1yt/pridel_header_3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
<h3>Slide 3</h3>
<p>This is the most awesome slide of them all</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .carousel {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .career-carousel {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    /* .carousel-inner {
        width: 240%;
        left: -70%;
    }*/
    .carousel-inner {
        width: 240%;
        left: -69%;
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        width: 5%;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 10000
        })
        $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            if (next.next().length > 0) {
                next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            } else {
                $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cloning each slide 3 times.

```
    $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        // Clone() creates one additional copy here
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        if (next.next().length > 0) {

            // And also here 
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
```

Get rid of the cloning statements, and you won't see overlapping slides. As a matter of fact, I don't see the purpose behind the entire code inside the `$.each()` function.

See a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a5zLhjmr/1/).

**EDIT**

Since you are creating a clone of the previous and next slide inside each slide, when they transition they overlay each other. It's not visible in the images, but quite visible in the text.

To overcome that, you need to hide the overlapping slides when they transition.

The following CSS should do it:

```
.carousel-inner > .item.prev.right > div:nth-child(2),
.carousel-inner > .item.prev.right > div:nth-child(3){
  display: none;
}

.carousel-inner > .item.active.left > div:nth-child(2),
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left > div:nth-child(3){
  display: none;
}
```

See a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a5zLhjmr/4/).

Comment: I have to show the previous & next images too or rather a preview of the other 2 slides. Please check my Demo link again to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the animation for a while - and then contemplated that sliding the container rather than the slides ought to be more efficient.

Here's the code:

```
.carousel-inner {
  width: 200%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  width: 50%; float: left;
}
.carousel-inner.prev {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner.move {
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out margin-left;
  -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out margin-left;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out margin-left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.active,
.carousel-inner > .item.out {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner.move.right {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner.move.left {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner.move.cycle > .item {
  float: right;
}
```

And the JS that goes with it:

```
return this.fx(function(state) {
    return show.items.map(function(items) {
        if (state.next < 0) {
            items.classList.add('cycle');
            state.next = items.childElementCount - 1;
        }else if (state.next == items.childElementCount) {
            items.classList.add('cycle');
            state.next = 0;
        }
        var anim = [].slice.call(items.children).reduce(function(res, el, idx) {
            if (idx == state.next) {
                state.curr = state.next;
                state.next = 0; res.next = el;
            }else if (idx == state.prev) {
                res.curr = el;
            }
            return res;
        }, {});
        anim.curr.classList.add('out');
        anim.curr.classList.remove('active');
        items.classList.add(state.ctrl);
        anim.next.classList.add('active');
        items.classList.add('move');
        show.end.run(items, function() {
            items.className = 'carousel-inner';
            anim.curr.classList.remove('out');
        }).classList.add(state.move);
        return state;
    }).run();
});
```